# SSL cert works in iOS VM, but won't work on device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ssl

I got an SSL certificate from OpenSSL (Not the best but free and accepted by chrome). It's used to make a secure payment to Stripe. Everything was working fine in the emulator, but when I loaded the app onto the device I get an error saying that "The certificate for this server is invalid."

Anyone know how to make this work? Looking for a correct solution (I have a feeling that will involve purchasing an SSL cert that's a bit more legit) as opposed to just allowing it a hacky way to just get it to run on the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trusted certificates are signed by a certificate authority, so while openssl is good for creating self signed certs to test with, you'll need to purchase a certificate for live use.

If you can install the certificate at both ends (client and server) then you can get away with a self signed certificate. This is basically what happens when you "accept the risk" in chrome.

Comment: That's what I figured. Wouldn't happen to know a cheap certificate authority would you?

Comment: I'm not sure if we're allowed to post recommendations on here, but I use startSSL. It's free for non-commercial use and quite cheap for commercial.